# How can I straighten out an extendable table that's starting to sag while still being able to take the middle out when needed?

Tags: wood, table

We have a wooden table with a removable middle section to make the table smaller/larger.

It's sagging in the middle. If I pull the legs in it straightens out.

What can I do to straighten the table out while still being able to remove the middle part?

I was thinking of screwing a metal plate on each side of the middle piece on the bottom ledge where it touches the outer sides but then I'd have to unscrew it every time I want to take the table apart -- and that might destroy the hole I use for the screw.

Is there any kind of connector thing I can attach that comes apart but still holds straight?

Note, the items on the table right now are not heavy. It sags even if I take everything off. And it's not wobbly. We can use the table and put heavy things on it without issues.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are the screws all tight on all the connecting/sliding hardware underneath?

Comment: Yes, they are. Everything that should be tight is.

Answer (score 4):

Those wooden rails in the middle of the table are the thing that extend and (are supposed to) keep the table rigid. They are effectively full extension drawer slides. There might be an issue with them and could be fixed by tightening things back up.

If you get underneath and forcibly unsag the table you might be able to see the play that is causing the sag.

Fixing the table may require taking that extension mechanism apart and creating new rails that have a tighter tolerance.

Comment: They are already pretty tight. The table is pretty old. I'm hoping I don't have to re-do the wooden rails. I'm wondering if there is anything else I could use maybe?

Comment: a millimeter of wiggle can create that visible sag, And those rails will wear out over time, that's just reality of a wood-on-wood gliding surface, eventually they will sand away the wood. Instead of creating whole new rails you might be able to glue in runners after routing away the worn surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

My parents have a table that takes ten or twelve leaves. There's a **leg in the middle**. It's attached to a board that's (I'd have to look but, I'd assume) attached width-wise to the underside of... probably the middle rails, so that it ends up staying in the middle no mater what configuration. All five legs are on wheels.